# CSS - Кастомный скроллбар и навигация по тегам html

Tags: html, css

Есть кастомный скроллбар.

```
   .scrollbar
    {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }


    #style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-track
    {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }

    #style-5::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
        width: 10px;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }

    #style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    {
        background-color: #0ae;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,
                           color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)),
                           color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
    }
```

Переход осуществляю:

```
<a href="#banner" id="unselectable" unselectable="on" class="button style2 scrolly">НИЖЕ</a>
```

Проблема в том, что если ставить 100vh , то переход по тегам не работает,а мне нужно, чтобы данный скроллинг заменял стандартный.

Comment: Сделай запускаемый сниппет.

Comment: мне жаль тебя расстраивать, но твой скроллбар будет работать только в хроме и новой опере. если тебе плевать на остальных юзеров - то ок.

Comment: @Алексей, я полагаю, в остальных браузерах будет применяться системные стили для полос прокрутки (и это хорошо)

Comment: @mymedia - Да, вы правы.

Comment: @Qwertiy ,А можно подробнее?

Comment: В редакторе нажимаешь на кнопочку Фрагмент кода - открывается окно типа jsfiddle. В нём делаешь [mcve] и вставляешь результат вместо того кода, который сейчас в вопросе.

Comment: @mymedia какой смысл тогда вообще в этих изъёживаний? за хлебом поеду на феррари, а на работу,отдых,путешествия,за город и перевозку семьи с детьми пожалуй буду осуществлять на москвиче-412...